# LLDB identify an object with its address

Tags: iphone, xcode, didreceivememorywarning, lldb

I'm working on an iPad application I recovered from a previous developer. Sometimes I get the following message :

```
Received memory warning.
applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning:
[ResultsListViewController respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x2b1c70
```

and the app stopped at

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

I understood that, after the application received a memory warning, the application is trying to execute a function from a class that was already deallocated. The problem is, as I said, I didn't developed the application, so I could not find where the problem occurred, even with the `NSZombies` enabled.

Is there a way to retrieve where the issue occurred, using LLDB (or any other way) with the object memory address (in my case 0x2b1c70)?

Comment: The *Object* was deallocated.

Comment: I know that, my question is how I can find where the object was used when the crash occurred to correct this memory management issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a symbolic breakpoint, this tutorial shows you how to use them: http://iosdevelopertips.com/debugging/tracking-down-exception-errors.html

Hope this helps!

Sam

Comment: Hi Sam, thanks for your feedback. I tried that, but it didn't work. may be I'm not using it right. I tried to put "[ResultsListViewController respondsToSelector:]" as Symbol in the symbolic breakpoint. Not sure it is the right way to do so...

Comment: I think you should use: EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

Comment: If thats doesn't work read this: [link](http://MobileDeveloperTips.com/debugging/updated-tracking-down-exc_bad_access-errors-with-nszombieenabled-in-xcode-4.html) read the first view comments on the article as well (someone was having the same issue)

Comment: Still no luck with EXC_BAD_ACCESS, I'll try to do what is preconized on the link you shared. Keep you informed. Thanks a lot

Comment: Forgot to say you can use instruments in Xcode and select the zombies template thats how I fixed the same issue. Good luck!

Comment: A question anyway, how to select the Zombies template? I did not find it in the Instruments templates.